# Identify language based on syntax sample

Tags: syntax

I'm getting the following e-mail message which is written in an interesting mark-up. What language is this?

```
{% assign merge_vars = api_trigger_properties | json_parse %}
{% if merge_vars.order == nil %}
{% abort_message('Did not receive merge variables') %}
{% endif %}  Track your package to see
exactly how close your things are. Your estimated delivery date
is between {{ merge_vars.shipping_estimation }}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its python Django web language to me....